# How to get rid of annoying "<SKMetalLayer: 0x135dd0160>: calling -display has no effect." error?

Tags: xcode, xcode7

> < SKMetalLayer: 0x135dd0160>: calling -display has no effect.

I know this question has been asked elsewhere and the answer is that this error is harmless but it is very annoying and I wish we knew what causes it and how to get rid of it.

Comment: I'm so sick of this error and I have no clue how to fix it...